# How to scale two game objects with different scale sizes proportionally?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, transform, scale, gameobject

I have two game objects, one for main canvas and other for editor (a dummy version).

The scale for main go is 1, 1, 1 and other one (dummy) is .3, .3, .3. What I want to do is scale the main gameobject proportionally based on the scale percent that the user sets to dummy go, how I can do this?

Comment: Maaaath. `original_scale_1 * current_scale_dummy / original_scale_dummy`

Comment: The below answer was useful, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DummyGameObject.transform.localScale = CanvasGameObject.transform.localScale * 0.33f; //or
DummyGameObject.transform.localScale = CanvasGameObject.transform.localScale / 3;
```